# Copy table data and populate new columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

So I'm trying to copy some data from database table to another. The problem is though, the target database table has 2 new columns that are required. I wanted to use the export/import wizard on SQL Server Management Studio but if I use that I will need to write a query for each table and I can only execute 1 query at a time. Was wondering if there are a more efficient way of doing it.

Here's an example of 1 table:

```
dbase1.dbo.Appointment { id, name, description, createdate }
dbase2.dbo.Appointment { id, name, description, createdate, auditby, auditat}
```

I have a total of 8 tables with those 2 additional columns. and most of them are related to each other via fk, so I wanted to use the wizard as it figures out which table gets inserted first. The problem with that is, it only works if I do a "copy data from one or more tables " and not the "write a query to specify data" (I use this to populate those two new columns).

I've been doing this very slow process in copying data as I'm using MVC Code First for my application and I dont have access to the server to be able to drop and create the table at my leisure. So I have to resort to this to maintain the data that I already have.

Comment: Are the two new fields allow null values?If yes, then you can try nested insert query. Something like this: INSERT INTO dbase2.dbo.Appointment VALUES (SELECT * FROM dbase1.dbo.Appointment). This type of query does worked for me several times. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: 8 isn't a whole lot. Can you not look at the list of 8 and determine on your own which order they need to be processed?

Comment: @V.P.Verma the query you posted in your comment will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea: temporarily disable the foreign key constraints in the destination database. Then it doesn't matter what order you run your inserts. In order to populate the two new and required columns, you just need to pick some stock values to put in there (since obviously these rows initially are not subject to initial auditing). For example:

```
INSERT dbase2.dbo.appointment
(id, name, description, createdate, auditby, auditat)
  SELECT id, name, description, createdate, 
    auditby = 'me', auditat = GETDATE()
  FROM dbo.appointment;
```

Since it seems the challenge is merely that the destination requires columns that aren't in the source, and that you need to determine what should be populated in these audit columns, this seems to solve multiple problems at once. You just need to figure out what to put in there instead of `'me'` and `GETDATE()`.

(To get the wizard to pull these 8 tables for you, you might be able to create a view similar to the select portion of the above query, but that's more work and it won't see the underlying FK constraints to generate them in the right order anyway.)

Comment: let me try this out real quick. so should i just straight up write the query then instead of the wizard. this will be my first time to do something like this so bear with me and my noob questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write the sql query for each of the insert processes in the order you want it. That would be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Default values` for these two columns

Like for AuditAt - Default Date i.e. `GetDate()`
For AuditBy - The Person ID/Name

Now, you can Insert into these tables without entering for these two columns

Comment: Just curious, who said there is a foreign key on the `auditby` column?

Comment: Sir, audit by, I assume, It is a user name and it should be a relational with a user table.

Comment: Well what it should be isn't necessarily what it is. I was actually only asking if I had missed something in the question; I don't think it's your place to tell the OP that he needs a foreign key on that table. Should he really store every single possible Windows auth login in a table, for example?

Comment: it is a fk, and i ran into a slight bump again, was wondering if you guys can be of help? it's how i dealt with the audit id and date i posted it on another thread as it's a slightly different on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033935/sql-server-auditing-a-table-with-code-first-mvc

Comment: @gdubs  In case of foreign key, disable it first and then set the default value to audit id and also assign some default value to date. Once the insertion is done please enable the foreign key constraint again.

Comment: @Kanavi currently I'm getting a cannot insert value for identity column in dbase2.dbo.appointment when IDENTITY_INSERT is off . I think that's after i disabled the constraint?

Comment: It is auto generate column. No need to set value for this column while doing insertion.

Comment: yeah but i need to set the id column. but i figured it out tho. thanks.